# What's the definition of these ID's stand for in Marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, id

I have seen a lot of different ID's in Marketing Cloud when using the extract tracking data. Does anyone have the definitions of these id's? Some of them I can find in the documentation but not all of them, and they are very poorly described.

Its ClientID, SendID, MailID, JobID, ListID, SendURLID, URLID and BatchID I'm talking about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just found all the definitions within this documentation:

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/data_extract_activity/extract_types/tracking_extract/tracking_extract_output/

**SendID (JOBID):** 
The ExactTarget identified associated to an email send.

**ClientID:** Specifies the ExactTarget account identifier associated with attribute set.

**SubscriberID:**
The  ExactTarget-generated subscriber unique identifier for a subscriber. SubscriberID relates to the Subscriber's SubscriberID column

**ListID:** The ExactTarget identified for the list that the job was sent to.

**BatchID:** Identifies the batch associated with a triggered email sent event. This value defaults to 0 for a marketing list send.

**EmailID:**
The email ID for the job

**SendURLID:**
A unique identifier for the individual URL in a send.

Comment: Is EmailID and JobId the same then?

Comment: @sfdcFanBoy, no. EmailID is the email and dosnt change. JobID is when the email i when the email i sent out.. so if you sent the mail out twice, it will have the same mailid but 2 different jobid